# Trust between 2 web applications

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api, oauth

We develop a web application that needs to integrate with another third party web application.
Let's call them MainApp and ThirdPartyApp.
There is a trust between our company and the third party app owning company, meaning we know and trust each other. Both apps will be administered by the same client. 
Both applications have their own database of users and login mechanism.
Both applications are hosted on different servers.

We need both apps to be able to call each other (web pages and rest APIs).
All the communication between both apps must be seamless without interaction from the user.
So once a user is logged into one application, it shouldn't prompt another login to access the other application.
When a request is made to the other application, it should be able to map to a user in its own database.
So the request isn't made on behalf of the calling application, but on behalf on the user currently logged into the calling application.
If it can help, we agreed on using the same UserCode in both applications.

My question, what are the best practices to implement this kind of trust between 2 applications?
Is there an OAuth grant flow that fits this scenario?

Comment: not sure about the part of oauth grant flow, but i guess SAML is basically what you are looking for: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SAML_2.0#Example_of_SAML_Assertion

Comment: Do you call from 1 webApi to another? Why you don't create a user in each API for Requests from the other?

Answer (score 0):

You'll find examples of Single Sign On approaches online; one such example:
https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/1140228/Implementation-of-Single-Sign-On-SSO-in-ASP-NET-MV

In this approach, by having a common configuration in both applications, you can achieve what you are looking for.  One of the requirements is to have the same machine key in the config (example from article):

```
<machineKey validationKey="E4451576F51E0562D91A1748DF7AB3027FEF3C2CCAC46D756C833E1AF20C7BAEFFACF97C7081ADA4648918E0B56BF27D1699A6EB2D9B6967A562CAD14767F163"
    decryptionKey="6159C46C9E288028ED26F5A65CED7317A83CB3485DE8C592"
    validation="HMACSHA256" decryption="AES" />
```

Obviously it goes without saying forms authentication is required.  if users are on the same domain, potentially you could use windows/Forms Active Directory?

Comment: The web applications aren't on the same domain